# Insert multiple records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am getting the list of students from 1 table it has 5 records. Now i added a checkbox at the end of each row.
Now what i want to do is insert all the data in a new table including the checkbox value as 1 if checked and 0 for unchecked.
New table will have a new colomn **date_id** which will be same for all 5 entries, and other columns will remain same as in table 1.
how to do this please help

Comment: did you try something.. show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean inserting multiple rows in mysql with a single query then:-

```
Insert into table table_name Values (date_id,values_of_a),(date_id,values_of_a),(date_id,values_of_a)... n number of records;
```

The values for a,b,c columns you already have from select query from table 1.

Comment: no you can not do it like this. inserting all entries in a single insert query will not be possible, you will have to execute insert queries for every all of them in a loop.

Comment: @AshishChopra You are incorrect, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html Check your facts. "INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);"

Comment: @allen213 hey thanks for correcting me, I was wrong.

Comment: @DevZero how to use a loop in this case means i first want to count the numbere of rows in table 1 and then insert values till count...??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?=(isset($table1Id))?$table1Id:'0'?>" />

<?php
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $each){
        if($each != "0"){
            $table1Id   = $each;
            ### retrive the details from table 1 here based on pk "$table1Id" and insert into table 2

        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

execute a for/ for each loop for entire list and execute insert query for every record in that list array

Comment: make a descriptive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, custom_value from old_table;
```

***Note:***

- The column count needs to match.
- You can specify any custom values in the select query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want using single query then

Insert into table your_table_name Values (date_id,values1),(date_id,values2),(date_id,values3),(date_id,values4),(date_id,values5)

or

store all value in list and execute for loop for every record in that list